# paper-dropdown inside iron-list is not positioned correctly

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am trying to place a paper-dropdown inside a collapsable iron-list (similar to the [demo here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list?view=demo:demo/collapse.html&active=iron-list)). But when I click on the dropdown menu, the menu items are displayed at a completely incorrect location. Below is a JSBin example of what I am seeing. If I place the same dropdown outside of the iron-list or even in paper-dialogs, they are working fine.

Can someone tell me whats going wrong or if there is any workaround.

http://jsbin.com/kedoziyewo/edit?html,output